# Setting a string member of a Struct in C

Tags: c, struct, printf

My problem is that when I run this function the output I get doesn't match up with what's expected. I'm attempting to print out members of a struct "Question" but for some reason the members "text" and "numAnswers" are the same when they should be different.

```
int AddQuestion()
{
    Question * question_added;
    Answer * answer_added;
    char input_buf[256];
    unsigned int num_answers;

    fflush(stdin);

    //Create the memory necessary for the new question.
    printf("Add a new question\n");
    question_added = (Question*)malloc(sizeof(Question));

    //Point the head to our new question.
    question_added->pNext = exam.phead; 
    exam.phead = question_added;

    //Get the question text from the user.
    printf("Please enter the question text below:\n");
    if(fgets(input_buf, sizeof(input_buf), stdin))
    {
        question_added->text = input_buf;
    }


    //Get the number of questions from the user
    printf("How many answers are there?:");
    if(fgets(input_buf, sizeof(input_buf), stdin))
    {
        question_added->numAnswers = atoi(input_buf);   
    }


    printf(question_added->text);
    printf("%d\n", question_added->numAnswers);


    return 1;
};
```

Here is some sample output:

```
MENU:
1. Add a new question.
2. Delete a question.
3. Print the Exam.
4. Quit.
1
Add a new question
Please enter the question text below:
TEST
How many answers are there?:1
1
1
```

I expect the output to be:
TEST
1

But it gives 1 for both. It's very confusing. Thanks in advance for your help in understanding what's going on here.

EDIT: Included Struct definition.

```
typedef struct Question
{
    char* text;
    unsigned int mark;
    Answer** answers;
    unsigned int numAnswers;
    struct Question* pNext;
}Question;
```

EDIT2: I've accepted the answer, thanks very much for all the helpful comments and effort!

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through the code while it runs? i believe once you will, you'll easily find the reason

Comment: Use `strcpy` for copying, this is not correct `question_added->text = input_buf;`.

Comment: It would help if you showed us the structure type definitions.  There are at least two plausible ways to write the structures (e.g. `char *text;` and `char text[64];`) and the ways to handle them correctly are different.  If the assignment `question_added->text = input_buf;` compiles, then you have a pointer rather than an array in the structure, but then you need to allocate space for a copy of the date that is read (`strdup()` anyone?).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've added the struct definition, thanks for your time and input.

Comment: @Ani Could you elaborate a little bit more please?

Comment: The assignment `question_added->text = input_buf;` copies the pointer for `input_buf` into the pointer `question_added->text` without moving the data.  When `input_buf` is reused, the value in `question_added->text` is overwritten; when the function exits, `input_buf` ceases to be valid so the data in `question_added->text` ceases to be valid.  You have to allocate space to store the string, and you have to copy the string into the allocated space.  The quickest way to do that is with `strdup()` — a function that allocates enough space for the string it is passed and copies the string into it.

Comment: @AndrewPolidori: For copying string you have to use `strcpy`. C doesn't have built in string type. So `question_added->text = input_buf;` wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is due to, same buffer `char input_buf[256];` used for two times.

```
printf("Please enter the question text below:\n");
if(fgets(input_buf, sizeof(input_buf), stdin)) 
{
    question_added->text = input_buf; // when you enter the string, question_added->text holds its address
}


//Get the number of questions from the user
printf("How many answers are there?:");
if(fgets(input_buf, sizeof(input_buf), stdin)) // but you are using the same buffer here
{
    question_added->numAnswers = atoi(input_buf);   
}
```

so the value at the `input_buf` is replaced by the second input. That is number. Due to this you are getting the Number 2 times!

So don't use the `input_buf` for second time to scan the number. Use some other buffer of use `num_answers` directly to scan!

Comment: I think `printf(question_added->text);` is fine.

Comment: @Ani: it is only fine if the user doesn't type `What %s of %d is %n going to represent?` as the question text.  Those conversion specifications are going to wreak havoc, especially the `%n` one which writes to a quasi-random location in your program (the other two merely read from quasi-random locations). Since you don't eliminate newlines, `printf("%s", question_added->text);` would be OK — it would print the saved newline anyway.

Comment: When I attempt to do this. I'm given:

Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD

EDIT: I see, the issue now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the answer to live beyond the scope of `AddQuestion()`, you'll probably want to use `strdup` or similar (preferably `strndup`). This requires you then call `free` on the `text` member. I.e.:

```
//Get the question text from the user.
printf("Please enter the question text below:\n");
if(fgets(input_buf, sizeof(input_buf), stdin))
{
    question_added->text = strndup(input_buf, sizeof(input_buf));
}


//Get the number of questions from the user
printf("How many answers are there?:");
if(fgets(input_buf, sizeof(input_buf), stdin))
{
    question_added->numAnswers = atoi(input_buf);   
}
```

Then later (before `free`ing the struct):

```
if (answer->text != NULL) {free(answer->text); answer->text == NULL;}
```

Then you can always use `input_buf` to scan `stdin`, and the answer text lasts beyond the scope of `AddQuestion`, which I assume is what you want. Just remember to `free` it!!